# Running and interacting with a Java program within a web application

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I have a Java program that has some input and output displayed through the monitor, and I want to create a web application that can run the Java program with some inputs and then receive any outputs from the program and display them using some JS functions, and I'm wondering how I could go about doing something like that.
I essentially want to create a GUI for my Java program using html/css and JavaScript.

I have already made a static webpage using html/JS that has the appropriate inputs, now I need to figure a way to start the Java program with those inputs and evaluate the outputs.

Comment: Well back in the day you _could_ have used a Java applet for this.  But now applets are deprecated.  Instead you can use Java as your backend technology.

Comment: You're going to have to find someway to turn your java application into something that looks like a web server.  You can bring those capabilities into the java code, you can expose the functions as an api, even if that api was just executing your java app from the command line and communicating with it via stdin and stdout.

Comment: This is where you get to find out how well you've separated your presentation logic from your business logic. If you have done it well then you might well be able to transfer all your business logic quite easily into a servlet, leaving jsps to handle inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

That's.. generally not how its done.

Instead you run a JVM (a java app) that keeps running and answers web requests itself. In other words, write a webapp. In java.

For example, by using [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/), [spark](https://sparkjava.com), etc - one of the many, many web frameworks for java.

Your web service can just answer in JSON, keep things simple, no problem. You can also set up your apache, nginx or whatever it is to redirect most calls to your usual web frameworks, and some subset to your jvm webserver that is otherwise 'hidden' from outside view (firewalled off).